# I have a php code that gets the data in database and display. now, I want it to display in pdf format

Tags: php, pdf

How to display data in php to pdf file format... I used fpdf but I don't know how my datas display in pdf format...

just an example in creating pdf but, i don't know how to do it with the php while loop, i get errors...

```
$pdf = new FPDF();
    $pdf->AddPage();

    $pdf->SetFont("Arial","B","20");
    $pdf->Cell(150,10,"My DATAS",1,1,"C");
    $pdf->Cell(150,10,"My data Loop",1,1,"C");

    $pdf->Output();
```

Here's my php code

```
<?php

require('fpdf.php');
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "rmsdb";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 



$from = '16/12/2015';
$to = '17/12/2015';
$sql = "select id, firstname, lastname, gender from walkin_member where datestamp between '$from' and 
'$to' order by datestamp asc";

$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    $row_cnt = $result->num_rows;
        echo $row_cnt;
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {


        $show = "id: " . $row["id"]. " - Name: " . $row["firstname"]. " " . $row["lastname"]. "<br>";
        echo $show;





    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}

$conn->close();
```

Comment: Study this [link](http://www.fpdf.org/en/tutorial/tuto5.htm) and make static file data to dynamic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this

```
$pdf = new FPDF();
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',16);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    $row_cnt = $result->num_rows;

    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

        $show= "officeCode: " . $row["officeCode"]. " - city: " . $row["city"]. " " . $row["phone"]. "\n";
        $pdf->Cell(150,10,"$show",1,1,"C");

    } 
}
ob_end_clean(); //if Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'FPDF error: Some data has already been output, can't send PDF file'
$pdf->Output();
```

Comment: thanks, it works. I did the same code but the difference is I don't have the " ob_end_clean();" <----- this thing helps to workout. That's what I really need to work the things up haha. thanks bro :)

Answer (score 1):

hello i am giving you a demo to generate pdf format using php and after analysing that you can generate pdf on your own according to your data which you want to generate.

Let's suppose i am having a HTML file **pdf.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<body>
<form action="pdf.php" method="post">
name:<input type=text name=t1 id=i1>
<br/>
password:<input type=text name=t2 id=i2>
<br/>
<input type=submit name=go value=pdf_generation>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

now when we will click on submit button then it will redirect to **pdf.php** which contains the following code -

```
<?php
extract($_REQUEST);
require('fpdf17/fpdf.php');
if(isset($go))
{
$pod=new FPDF();
$pod->AddPage();
$pod->setFont("Arial","B",16);
$pod->cell(100,10,"welcome",1,1);
$pod->cell(50,10,"Name:",1,0);
$pod->cell(50,10,"$t1",1,1);
$pod->cell(50,10,"Password:",1,0);
$pod->cell(50,10,"$t2",1,1);
$pod->output();
}
?>
```

if you found it useful , feel free to apreciate my answer by accepting my answer.